# How to stop/start IIS 7 application through command line?

Tags: iis-7, command-line, batch-file, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I would like to create a batch file to start one IIS application, and stop another one.

How it can be done using command line?

How to combined it in batch file?

Comment: For [remote invocations](https://serverfault.com/questions/274831/is-there-a-way-to-make-my-local-appcmd-exe-to-refer-to-a-remote-server/703881#703881)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Configuring-IIS-7-command-line-Appcmdexe-Part1.html

Put this into a file with `.bat` extension.

```
@echo off

appcmd start sites "site1"
appcmd stop sites "site2"
```

**Update**

Just ensure that `appcmd` is available anywhere by adding `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\` to the `PATH` environment variable of your system. Alternatively, you can use the full path to `appcmd.exe` in the batch file.

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to mention that. You can append `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\` to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: this also works with application pools, just change `sites` to `apppool`

Comment: appcmd needs high privileges to read file redirection.config: `Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions`